# Emptying arraylist in loop

Tags: java, arrays

How can I empty the `attributeList` every time it has "added" the value to `largeAttributeList`?. I've tried .clear() but then the largeAttributeList loses all the values.

```
ArrayList<String> attributeList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> largeAttributeList = new 
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < attribute.getLength(); i++) {
        String current = attribute.item(i).getTextContent();
        if(current.equals("Identifier")){
            largeAttributeList.add(attributeList);
        }
        else{
            attributeList.add(current);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Examples of your input vs expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inisialize your array inside your loop :

```
....
ArrayList<String> attributeList;
for (int i = 0; i < attribute.getLength(); i++) {
    String current = attribute.item(i).getTextContent();
    if (current.equals("Identifier")) {
        largeAttributeList.add(attributeList);
        attributeList = new ArrayList<>();//<<<-------------
    } else {
        attributeList.add(current);
    }

}
```

Comment: This would initialize it at every round of the for. While he only wants to empty it when added so I would move your suggestion into the `if(current.equals("Identifier")){`. That way it would always be a new one once he added it, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a copy of a list before its clearing:

```
    largeAttributeList.add(new ArrayList<>(attributeList));
```

Update: YCF_L solution is obviously better than my one cause there is no necessity to obtain overhead and give additional work for GC.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
largeAttributeList.add(attributeList);
```

You are not making a copy of attributeList, but adding its reference to largeAttributeList. I think the best solution would be to re-initialize attributeList in the loop:

```
List<List<String>> identifierAttributes = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
List<String> attributes = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < attribute.getLength(); i++) {        
    String current = attribute.item(i).getTextContent();
    if(current.equals("Identifier")){
        identifierAttributes.add(attributes);
        attributes = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    else {
        attributes.add(current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `ArrayList` object for `attributeList` when you add `attributeList` in `largeAttributeList` :

```
largeAttributeList.add(new ArrayList<String>(attributeList));
```

In this way when you execute `attributeList.clear()` you clear only `attributeList` and not the list object added in `largeAttributeList`.